# How to add a large number of visible arrows in Three.js using THREE.ArrowHelper

Tags: javascript, three.js, nw.js

edited: specifying the use of ArrowHelper 
I wish to generate a large number of arrows on a 2D plane, to represent a vector field. The number of vectors varies, but is typically 20000.

Using THREE.ArrowHelper, I can achieve this, but it is tremendously slow, so I am thinking there must be a better way. How could I be repaint the field using a subsampled number of vectors when zoomed out and is there a way to dynamically calculate and add only what the renderer will need?

added:
I create it using the snippet of the code inserted below. The loop generates a 2D vector field at the x,y locations of a parametric surface.

```
// set default color
var hex = 0x00ff00;
var u,v,xx,yy,ii,dir,mag,origin;
// loop through
Geometry[i].vertices.forEach(function(point,j) 
{
  xx = Math.floor((point.x-data[i].x0)/data[i].dx);
  yy = Math.floor((point.y-data[i].y0)/data[i].dy);
  ii = data[i].nx*yy+xx;

  u = data[i].frame[data[i].xvec][ii];
  v = data[i].frame[data[i].yvec][ii];
  mag = Math.pow(u*u+v*v,.5);
  dir = new THREE.Vector3( u, v, 1 );
  origin = new THREE.Vector3( point.x+data[i].dx/2,
                              point.y+data[i].dy/2, 1 );

  data[i].arrowHelper[j] = new THREE.ArrowHelper( dir.normalize(), 
                                                  origin,
                                                  data[i].scale*mag, 
                                                  hex);
  scene.add( data[i].arrowHelper[j] );

});
```

I just tested on a more powerful machine, where it runs *smoother*, but still taking a significant performance hit.

I can display and smoothly render the parametric surface and even a 1e06 underlying texture no problem, but the ArrowHelpers are causing the performance hit.

Comment: What part is actually slow? Are you using 20,000 draw calls? If so, the answer is to draw them all in 1 draw call.

Comment: you dont need to dynamically calculate what is visible; webgl does that automatically (frustum culling).

Comment: Updated the question with more details.

Comment: You'll need to merge everything into most likely two draw calls - one to draw the lines, and another to draw the heads. Issuing 20.000 draw calls (or more, how many per arrowhelper?) every tick is what's slowing this down.

Comment: Thanks @pailhead - do you mean such as referenced here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268228/render-webgl-non-contiguous-lines-as-a-single-object ?

Comment: that would be a start, you also would need a way to control these which cant be done without a custom shader

Comment: I implemented the THREE.LinePieces and it worked a treat for static vectors. Currently, I am redrawing them when they change, which isn't too often and is sufficient for my requirements is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @pailhead, the solution was to plot the arrows as two sets of lines calls with THREE.LinePieces. Following the original question's code, the arrow base is then implemented as. The line[i] is removed and recalculated when the vectors change.

```
// set default color
var hex = 0x00ff00;
var u,v,xx,yy,ii;
// initialise arrow bases
var lines = new THREE.Geometry();
// loop through
Geometry[i].vertices.forEach(function(point,j) 
{
    // rescale
    xx = Math.floor((point.x-data[i].x0)/data[i].dx);
    yy = Math.floor((point.y-data[i].y0)/data[i].dy);
    ii = data[i].nx*yy+xx;
    u = data[i].frame[data[i].xvec][ii]*data[i].scale;
    v = data[i].frame[data[i].yvec][ii]*data[i].scale;
    lines.vertices.push(
      new THREE.Vector3(point.x+data[i].dx/2, point.y+data[i].dy/2,1), 
      new THREE.Vector3(point.x+data[i].dx/2+u, point.y+data[i].dy/2+v,1)
    );

});
var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color:hex})
line[i] = new THREE.LineSegments( lines, material);
scene.add(line[i]);
```

three.js r.73

Comment: @Neil good spot - I omitted lines irrelevant to the SO question, but forgot to remove the j index they rely on.